# Use armature to pose nested meshes without inner mesh showing through

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature, weight-painting, pose-mode

I created a blue hollow box mesh object with another red box-shaped mesh object inside it. I added simple surface subdivision modifiers to both. Then, I added an armature and CTRL-P to parent the armature to both of the objects selecting "armature deform with automatic weights."
[image: armature in nested meshes]

Scene:

[image: scene]

Then, I went into Weight Paint mode and painted weights for each bone in the armature for each of the meshes.
[image: weight paint]

However, often when I pose the armature, the red inner box shows through the blue hollow box. This is true even if I apply the subdivision modifier with lots of subdivisions.
[image: armature deform fail]

I would like both objects to deform together no matter how small on the z-axis they are (how thin they are) so that the red inner box never shows through the blue hollow box.

Is there a way that I can achieve this in Blender?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a *Mesh Deform cage*. That's an invisible object (=disabled for render). In the screenshot, it's the wireframe cube. It is a child of the armature and is deformed by it. The cube objects inside have a *Mesh Deform* modifier on them and the cage will deform them with help of this modifier. Bind them with the button when the armature is in the rest position.

[image: mesh deform example]